# Importing git npm modules results in undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, node-modules, package.json

I have made a npm module in a private git repo and I'm trying to access it in another application.
I'm using reactjs, webpack and npm

So I have the module:

```
    dist
    src
    |   form-mapper
        |   formMapper.js
    |   myfile.js
    |   index.js
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

Webpack.config.js is like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Package.json is like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-awesome-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

formMapper.js as 2 functions that I'm trying to export:

```
    export function mapForm() {
        // some code
    }
    export function mapUiFormToBackEnd() {
        // some code
    }
```

And index.js:

```
import * as FormMapper from './form-mapper/formMapper'

export { mapForm, mapUiFormToBackEnd } from './form-mapper/formMapper'
export default FormMapper
```

I've tried a lot of things in index.js so I let everything here just to show you guys what I've already tried.

In my app that needs to use this module I import the module using npm (git+ssh://...) which is working since I can see my module inside node_modules.
When I try to import using:

```
import FormMapper from 'my-awesome-module'

componentDidMount() {
   FormMapper.mapForm()
}
```

I have this error:

```
my-awesome-module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.mapForm is not a function
```

That's my first time trying to create my own npm module and I clearly don't understand everything. I tried several guide but it seems I'm not abla to make it right.

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
When I log my import in my application

```
import FormMapper from 'my-awesome-module'

componentDidMount() {
   console.log(FormMapper)
   FormMapper.mapForm()
}
```

I see an empty object `{}` getting logged

Comment: Is it literally called `module-name`?

Comment: No I changed the name in the post, let me change it again so it's not confusing

Answer (score 1):

update your formMapper.js in a more proper way

```js
const mapForm = () => {
    // Code here
}
const mapUiFormToBackEnd = () => {
    // Code here
}
module.exports = {mapForm, mapUiFormToBackEnd }
```

on your index.js

```js
// If you just want the mapForm and mapUiFormToBackEnd
const {mapForm, mapUiFormToBackEnd} = require('./form-mapper/formMapper');

// Or if you just want to get all it's fucntion just import it like this
const FormMapper = require('./form-mapper/formMapper') // No need for *

// export the whole FormMapper
module.exports = FormMapper;

// If you want to export a specific functions inside FormMapper
module.exports = {mapForm, mapUiFormToBackEnd }
```

Comment: I edited my post. the formMapper.js exists in my project, I'm exporting 2 functions from it, that's why I used `import * as FormMapper from './form-mapper/formMapper'` instead of `import FormMapper from './form-mapper/formMapper'`

Comment: I tried your suggestions, still getting the error. I'll keep your suggestions tho since it's cleaner

Comment: I don't see any errors in your example code. That should be working, I think the problem is the way you import it, try to use require and module.exports. I will update my answer

Comment: I just tried module.exports and still the same issue... I really don't know what's happening

Comment: I think the problem is in the ` src//form-mapper/formMapper.js ` , because I tried the same method over and over when I am creating npm packages, and I didn't get an error like that

Comment: At the beginning, formMapper.js was in my main project and everything was working, I moved it to this new project to create a npm module. formMapper.js shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I edited my orignal post to add more info